# How To Ignore Access Violation Exception From External Dll - .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, pdf, access-violation, .net-6.0, dinktopdf

I'm using DinkToPDF dll to convert an XML to PDF.

> I need to generate 2000 PDF's.

So I try to do put the PDF generation logic inside for loop.
It generates first 2 or 3 PDF's and then in the next iteration crashes with a native Exception

This is my PDF generation class. Generate() method will be called 2000 times inside a forloop

> ```
> public static class PDFEngine
> {
>     public static void Generate(string html, string directory, string fileName)
>     {
>         var converter = new BasicConverter(new PdfTools());
>
>         converter.PhaseChanged += Converter_PhaseChanged;
>         converter.ProgressChanged += Converter_ProgressChanged;
>         converter.Finished += Converter_Finished;
>         converter.Warning += Converter_Warning;
>         converter.Error += Converter_Error;
>
>         var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
>         {
>             GlobalSettings = {
>                 ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
>                 Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
>                 PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
>             },
>             Objects = {
>                 new ObjectSettings() {
>                     PagesCount = true,
>                     HtmlContent = html,
>                     WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" },
>                     HeaderSettings = { FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true },
>                     FooterSettings = { FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]" }
>                 }
>             }
>         };
>
>         byte[] pdf = converter.Convert(doc);
>
>         if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
>         {
>             Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
>         }
>
>         using (FileStream stream = new FileStream($"{directory}\\{fileName}", FileMode.Create))
>         {
>             stream.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
>         }
>     }
>
>     private static void Converter_Error(object sender, DinkToPdf.EventDefinitions.ErrorArgs e)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] {0}", e.Message);
>     }
>
>     private static void Converter_Warning(object sender, DinkToPdf.EventDefinitions.WarningArgs e)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("[WARN] {0}", e.Message);
>     }
>
>     private static void Converter_Finished(object sender, DinkToPdf.EventDefinitions.FinishedArgs e)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("Conversion {0} ", e.Success ? "successful" : "unsucessful");
>     }
>
>     private static void Converter_ProgressChanged(object sender, DinkToPdf.EventDefinitions.ProgressChangedArgs e)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("Progress changed {0}", e.Description);
>     }
>
>     private static void Converter_PhaseChanged(object sender, DinkToPdf.EventDefinitions.PhaseChangedArgs e)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("Phase changed {0} - {1}", e.CurrentPhase, e.Description);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected
> memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

[image]

Since this is an Exception generating from an Unmanaged dll, I can't catch it.
[image]

I tried adding

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

during every loop but it's not working.
I'm fully aware that this error is fatal and not good to continue but I don't have a way to process 2000 files.

Is there any other way to either

1. Suppress the Exception and continue loop
2. Resolve this error by running it in a different app domain or something?

Comment: Code is text, please post it as text, not images.

Comment: Attached code @GuruStron

Comment: do you have to create a new PdfTools & Converter every time?

Comment: Somebody has something to say about that engine https://medium.com/@jodsonleandro/the-danger-of-dinktopdf-library-f0e221d2bcad

Comment: I got this example from this official Repo @pm100. Although they're not managing it, It works pretty well if I don't put the convert logic inside a for-loop

Comment: https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/blob/master/DinkToPfd.TestConsoleApp/Program.cs

Comment: The simple answer is: You can't. Access violations can't be caught in C#. It's theoretically possible by using either a C++/CLI wrapper or when still using .NET Framework, but it is highly discouraged. Look for a fixed or different PDF converter.

Comment: When I run individualy everything works fine. Issue is when looping. Is there any way we can clear memory or relink dll or running on new app domain or something similar like that? Since it fails only in loop I'm confused

Comment: The process will be irrevocably terminated. The only real way to recover is to do all of this in a helper process that you spawn from the main process (you can use the same executable with different parameters) and keep track of where you were in the process, so you can resume it. It is very probable some unmanaged invocation somewhere is corrupting the stack or the heap in a way that isn't noticed until a few cycles in, but unless you fancy digging in deep there's no way to fix that.

Comment: I found one working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I was able to make it work with a different way.

My intention is to run in 2000 times.
My issue was when I put it inside the loop, I'm getting native exceptions

To make it work for my need

1. I removed the loop and generate PDF only for a single file. This file name I receive in a commandline argument
2. Then I created another console app that got a 2000 iteration loop and it'll call the main app as a `Process.Start();` I can pass the filename as arguments

[image]

This way I managed to make for any number of iterations for time being. Since each process got different PID now Memory issue is not there

[image]